# Gitlab CI script: exclude branches

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, auto-build

I'm trying to improve the project building script, described in YML-file, the improvement itself seems quite trivial, but the idea of accidentally ruining the auto-builds scares me a bit.

Right now there are several branches, version tags and other stuff in the project.

A development branch, not built by the runners would be of use, because copying a huge project somehow between virtual machines to test the build on different platforms is not convenient at all. So, I want to exclude from builds some "prj-dev" branch.

And there we have:

```
stages:
 - build
 - linuxbuild
job:
 tags:
 - win2008build
 stage: build
 script:
  # something complex

job1:
 tags:
 - linux
 stage: linuxbuild
 script:
  # something else complex
```

I googled and found a solution like:

```
stages:
 - build
 - linuxbuild
job:
 tags:
 - win2008build 
 branches:
  except:
    - *dev-only
```

But it seems that our pipelines are quite different, the tags are not git tags, they are pipeline tags. So, I'm considering rather to use a config like:

```
stages:
 - build
 - linuxbuild
job:
 tags:
 - win2008build 
 except:
   branches:
    - *dev-only
```

...which would mean "build as usual, but not my branch". There are complications in trying it both ways, I'm pretty sure someone should know the recipe for sure.

So, if you please, -- how do I exclude my dev branch without changing the pipelines, config only? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You cannot without changing the .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Oh, pretty clear!

Those fragments in my questions ARE parts of .gitlab-ci.yml, which is being used in the project. I wonder about about the correct way to chage THE file.

Comment: What exactly is not working? It seems to be okay at first glance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

All you need to do is use `except` in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file and add your branches directly below like this:

```
mybuild:
    stage: test
    image: somedockerimage
    script:
        - some script running
    except:
        - branch-name
```

This is working on my project without problems.

Comment: Instead of 'except', you can use 'only' to specify one branch which should be considered for builds exclusively.

Comment: @Thomas How does this work in version 13 of GitLab?

Comment: I would like to build for all tags. Except the master branch.